Can't create custom list display form on sub sites (SP SE on-premises)
I can’t create any custom forms in lists in any sub sites in SharePoint Designer. It lets me create new display & edit forms in the top level of sites, but not in any sub site lists.
As a test I created a brand new list in a sub site of a site collection which just has the Title field. In the top level of the site collection (root web), I can create new custom forms for all the lists there. But in the sub sites I can't. Even in this new Test list that just has the title field. So there have been no customisations on this test list.

Which version of SharePoint is this (2010, 2016, 2019, etc.)?
Based on what you're describing, the form modification is behaving as template at the root site (such as master page).
I recommend checking to see if there are other templates that's applied which prevents you from applying your changes. Also, if it's preventing you from form modification and I'm guessing that it's applying the default MS form, and your form design code is not meant to overwrite the default MS form.
BTW, I would recommend using Visual Studio instead of SharePoint designer as to form modification.

SharePoint SE on-premises.
After further testing it turns out that there was one sub site I was able to create a custom form on the lists. But that was one sub site out of testing about 20.
